# How to apply a security patch to an existing docker image?

Tags: docker, security, patch, docker-container, docker-image

IF there is a docker image using a particular base image is running as a container and there is a new security upgrade for the base image. What is the best practice to apply that security patch to the docker image.

Also how to know if there is a security patch available for the base image .

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have a Dockerfile that is based on an image called "Base:latest" and you've built an image called "MyImage:latest:latest"

If "Base:latest" has updated with security updates, you need to rebuild your "MyImage:latest".

Containers are image instances, so if you need the security updates that need to be reflected in a container, the container should be re-created based on the "MyImage:latest" image.

Notice that you wouldn't want to use the "latest" tag for base images in production, because you won't be able to reproduce the same deployed environment, so the best practice is to use a specific version tag like "1.0". If an update is available, you'll need to updated your Dockerfile from "Base:1.0" to "Base:1.1".

So if your image is based on another image and you want to run security updates without waiting for a new and updated version of the base image, you can run a security update command in your Dockerfile and make sure to rebuild your image occasionally and recreate the container.

You could probably automate this process using tools like [Watchtower](https://github.com/containrrr/watchtower) by automatically rebuild your image on a regular basis and then recreate your container.

Another option is to run automated updates in the container level, probably by using a script that runs every day, but you should take into consideration the impact on the running process load-wise (networking, cpu, etc.)